# Lumia 820 display not working - need to move files to PC

Tags: 8.1, file-transfer

Accidentally dropped my phone down. Now the screen is cracked and display is not working. I have some media files stored in both internal and external memory. How can I move those files to PC or delete them?

Comment: Do you have a pin lock on your phone?

Comment: Yes. I have pin lock on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have PIN lock, I don't think it would be possible to access anything on the Phone Memory. Let others reply and see if there is any workaround.