# Access to data via USB without using the screen

Tags: usb, screen

I have a Nokia Luia 535 (Windows 8.1) with a broken screen. There is no pin, my problem is that when I connect it to the PC it asks if I want to use USB access for data instead of only charge, and I can't press on yes.

There is any way to acces to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/11346/106

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is not duplicated, I don't have pin code, it is totally diferent.